# How facebook manages user profiles in database?

Tags: facebook, algorithm, data-structures, soa

E.g. I've 350 friends mapped in my profile, so it's not necessarily all my friends' data  stored in single data store. So how facebook maps all my connections when I load my profile, in real time? Do they use, trie data structure/graph data structure?

Comment: They almost certainly use a relational database.

Comment: If you mean what kind of data structures they use in the application after querying the database, no one here is likely to be able to answer that. Only the FB programmers know the specifics.

Comment: @Barmar Facebook most certainly doesn't use a relational database; it's probably the most pathological single application ever for such a data structure. It uses a custom graph store.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about internal Facebook data structures.

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned in the comments, only FB programmers would know the specifics. Second best alternative would be to read their engineering page:

https://www.facebook.com/Engineering

Regarding your query, following post should give you some insight:

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/tao-the-power-of-the-graph/10151525983993920

also check:

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/linkbench-a-database-benchmark-for-the-social-graph/10151391496443920

There are many other posts which gives insight about their infrastructure, benchmarking, caching etc. You could search for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think  it is a graph representation . The friend of friends function does look similar to a BFS search algorithm.

I do not think it is a trie.The list of friends might be stored as a suffix tree.